# Refer environment variable in Run.json for Fleet IDE

Tags: jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-fleet

I am working on setting up the JetBrains Fleet for JavaScript development.

Here is my hard coded run.json look like.

```json
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "command",
        "name": "local test",
        "program": "npm",
        "args": [
            "run",
            "test",
            "ssoni_local"
        ],
    }
]
```

Instead of using `ssoni` (my username), I would like to use `${USERNAME}` environment variable so the same `run.json` file can be used my other team members as well.

How can I achieve the same?

Also same needs for the hostname variable as well. Instead of hardcoding machine name want to use an environment variable.

Comment: These are built-in macros: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/built-in-macros.html Not sure if you can **refer* to existing ENV variable here though... (but you can *specify your own* ENV variables)

Comment: An idea though (rather inconvenient though): what if you target a custom shell/batch script where you can get all this info from ENV and make the actual execution of the needed program/command?

Answer (score 0):

Fleet supports [several macros variables](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/built-in-macros.html) in run configuration json file, but the `${USERNAME}` is not supported. I have filled a request for this: *[FL-19179](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/FL-19179/Run-Configurations-support-user-name-macros-variable) Run Configurations: support user name macros variable*

Please feel free to vote for in in Fleet issue tracker.