# Fleet C++ run.json

Tags: c++, config, jetbrains-fleet

I've just read this question:
[How to create and configure run.json in the new JetBrains Fleet for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74623155/how-to-create-and-configure-run-json-in-the-new-jetbrains-fleet-for-c)

But I can't make it run, I don't know what to add into the run.json:

```
{
     "configurations": [
         {
             "type": "command",
             "name": "run",
             "dependsOn": [
                 "build"
             ],
             "program": "C:/Users/Khakis/Documents/C++ Learning/<I don't know what to put here>",
         },
         {
             "type": "command",
             "name": "build",
             "program": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
             "args": [
                 "$PROJECT_DIR$/main.cpp",
                 "-std=c++17",
                 "-pthread",
                 "-O2",
                 "-o",
                 "solution"
             ],

         },
     ]
}
```

Thanks for help.
In the C++ Learning I have this:

```
Directory: C:\Users\Khakis\Documents\C++ Learning

.cache
.fleet
CMakeFiles
CPlusPlusLearning.dir
Debug
x64
ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
ALL_BUILD.vcxproj.filters
cmake_install.cmake
CMakeCache.txt
CMakeLists.txt
compile_commands.json
CPlusPlusLearning.sln
CPlusPlusLearning.vcxproj
CPlusPlusLearning.vcxproj.filters
learning.cpp
ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj
ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj.filters
```