# Some questions about run.json of JetBrains new IDE Fleet

Tags: kotlin, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-fleet

[image]

I'm a beginner in coding, and as u can see, I don't know how to configure the `run.json` file in Fleet, especially the `program`. Hope that someone could help me, thanks so much!!!

I have read the notice from JetBrains, but I still don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: If you are a newbie in coding, why don't you start with Intellij IDEA Community Edition first?

Comment: Try checking the docs to see how `run.json` should be written: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/run-configs.html -- this page has examples + Fleet will help with code completion as you type. A few more general examples (not specific to Kotlin): 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74366488/refer-environment-variable-in-run-json-for-fleet-ide 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74167032/jetbrains-fleet-running-flutter-project/74184181#74184181 And yes, using IntelliJ IDEA Community would be a better choice for a new person to Kotlin and coding overall

Answer (score 0):

Type `command` is used for executing [raw commands](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/execute-raw-commands.html). See the description of what the **program** is in the **Command properties** which is

> Shell command to execute

i.e. this is a program executable which is installed on your machine.

If you want to run Main Kotlin class, it is better to use [Editor gutter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/getting-started-with-kotlin-in-fleet.html#run_from_gutter) a d run your program from the green icon in gutter:
[image]